# unable to click on checkbox in C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have tried using `Id` and `xpath` to identify and locate the element. Element is getting identified however, when I perform `click` operation on it, gives `InvalidOperationException`. I have tried using `Actions` as well but no success.

Comment: You can try with javascript executor.

Comment: could you share the html code of the checkbox?

Comment: code for Checkbox:-
<input name="<some name>" type="checkbox" id="<some id>" title="<someTitle>" value="<somevalue>">

Comment: Highlighted programming words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checkbox in my selenium tests and it works fine, I have something like

```
if (!checkbox.IsChecked())
{
    checkbox.TryClick();
}
```

Comment: I used javascriptexecutor for this and it worked however, what u have suggested is also correct –

Answer (score 0):

```
var ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath)); //or ID or Name
var check = ele.Selected;
if (check == false)
   ele.Click();
```

Comment: I used javascriptexecutor for this and it worked however, what u have suggested is also correct